# How to give ajax success function response as input to datatables

Tags: json, ajax

I write a script code that calls the getdata.php by sending a value ,i am getting the success function response in json format it look like this.

my script code:

```
<script>
 function getId(val) {
 alert(val);
    $.ajax({
     type: "post",
    url: "getdata.php",
    data: 'id=' + val,
    dataType: "JSON",                  
    success: function(response){ 
      console.log(response);
    }                       
            /*$('#city').dataTable({
             "bProcessing": true,
             "sAjaxSource": "JSON.parse(this.response)",
             "aoColumns": [
                    { mData: 'id' } ,
                    { mData: 'vid' },
                    { mData: 'date' },
                    { mData: 'latitude' },
                    { mData: 'longitude' },
                    { mData: 'speed' },
                    { mData: 'batery' },
                    { mData: 'totalkm' },
                    { mData: 'intrkm' },
                    { mData: 'control' }

            ]
    }); */


 });
}
</script>
```

and my response json data :

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":[{"id":"1","vid":"A0001","date":"2019-02-07 15:58:53","latitude":"17.00","longitude":"82.20","speed":"25","batery":"98","totalkm":"8","intrkm":"8","control":"0"},{"id":"2","vid":"A0001","date":"2019-02-07 15:58:53","latitude":"17.10","longitude":"82.30","speed":"26","batery":"97","totalkm":"15","intrkm":"15","control":"0"}]}
```

console.log(response); gives like

```
{sEcho: 1, iTotalRecords: 2, iTotalDisplayRecords: 2, aaData: Array(2)}
aaData: Array(2)
0: {id: "1", vid: "A0001", date: "2019-02-07 15:58:53", latitude: "17.00", 
longitude: "82.20", …}
1: {id: "2", vid: "A0001", date: "2019-02-07 15:58:53", latitude: "17.10", 
longitude: "82.30", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
iTotalDisplayRecords: 2
iTotalRecords: 2
sEcho: 1
```

Now, how to give the response of ajax call to datatables sAjax source and read the colums data and present it in #city.
please help me i am strucked here.

Comment: Try out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633022/how-to-show-json-response-data-in-datatable-using-jquery-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

DataTables has the ability to read data from virtually any JSON data source that can be obtained by Ajax. This can be done, in its most simple form, by setting the ajax option to the address of the JSON data source.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#city').DataTable( {
        "ajax": 'getdata.php?any_value=1'
    });
});
```

Refer more details : https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Comment: Your JSON should be like this `{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170,750"
    ]]`

Comment: @Srinivas Have you fixed ?